# How to display data in ExtJS tree received using jsonArray from struts2 action

Tags: json, extjs

I am new to ExtJs and I am just having a hard time reading the json array received from struts2 application.

Following is the json array that I received from struts application

```
[{
  "children": [{
    "children": [],
    "cls": "file",
    "id": 11,
    "leaf": true,
    "text": "A Child 1"
  }, {
    "children": [],
    "cls": "file",
    "id": 12,
    "leaf": true,
    "text": "A Child 2"
  }],
  "cls": "folder",
  "id": 10,
  "leaf": false,
  "text": "A Folder"
}]
```

it works fine if I save it in the .json file and call it using dataUrl: 'json.json'. But when I call it using dataUrl: 'myAction.action', the data is not loaded.

I would really appreciate if someone could throw some insight on something I am missing here. Following is my .js, which is similar to example provided by extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    // shorthand
    var Tree = Ext.tree;

    var tree = new Tree.TreePanel({
        useArrows: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        animate: true,
        enableDD: true,
        containerScroll: true,
        border: false,
        // auto create TreeLoader
        dataUrl: 'myAction.action',

        root: {
            nodeType: 'async',
            text: 'Ext JS',
            draggable: false,
            id: 'src'
        }
    });

    // render the tree
    tree.render('tree-div');
    tree.getRootNode().expand();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `dataUrl` is valid at runtime. Use FireBug or the Safari console to see the XHR request for `myAction.action` - my guess is that you might need to change it to `/something/myAction.action`.

Comment: Thanks Julian. I am dumb, that's what it was. I was asking totally wrong question to my problem. Thanks though.